# Bootstrap / Masonry column width issues

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

http://uniquelyrosha.com/

I have columns set to col-xs-4 each, but yet it bugs out and removes the third column.  My code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $container = $('.products');

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.fadeIn(300);
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.product_image',
        isAnimated: true
    });
});
});
```

And my html is like this:

```
<div class="product_image col-xs-4"><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="/photos/1014919_10101744331352953_8981394028326535000_o.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Why are the containers positioned absolutely with inline-styles?

Comment: This is something that masonry does to it.  It is not the CSS that I have applied.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `position:absolute` ? this is wrong approach, To nest cols in bootstrap always use `"row"` like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
     <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but once again in col-xs-4 you will have mobile screen divided in 3 col so prefer to use `col-md-4 col-sm4 col-xs-12`

Comment: This is something that masonry does to it.  It is not the CSS that I have applied.